# While Loop looping only once when using getline from file

Tags: c++, while-loop, getline

I have this small bit of code:

```
fileopen.open(file_name);
while (getline(fileopen, line, ',')){
    string temp;
    vector<string> mug;
    temp = line;
    stringstream ss(temp);
    while (getline(ss, temp, ' ')){
        mug.push_back(temp);
    }
    stringstream conv;
    double vol, cos;
    conv << mug.at(1);
    conv >> vol;
    stringstream().swap(conv);
    conv << mug.at(3);
    conv >> cos;
    mugs.push_back(make_tuple(mug.at(0), vol, mug.at(2), cos));
    stringstream().swap(conv);
    stringstream().swap(ss);
    temp.clear();
}
sort(mugs.begin(), mugs.end(), sort_by);
for (int i = 0; i < mugs.size(); i++){
    cout << "Country: " << get<0>(mugs[i]) << " ";
    cout << ", Volume: " << get<1>(mugs[i]) << " ";
    cout << ", Material: " << get<2>(mugs[i]) << " ";
    cout << ", Price: " << get<3>(mugs[i]) << "\n";
}
```

I have multiple clears and `stringstream().swap()`'s because it is a well known issue. `<sstream>` seems to interrupt iterations for `while` loops. However, even this doesn't seem to be working. The input given from the file is as follows:

```
RUS 0.1 Wood 20
USA 0.4 Glass 0.5
```

The current code prints the first line as needed, but fails to iterate and print the second line. Any suggestions?

I have tried using `continue` and `goto` for solving this problem. None of those solutions have worked out.

Comment: On a side note: consider using `std::strtod()` or `std::stod()` to parse your `string` values into `double`s, instead of using `stringstream`. And you don't need to `swap()` a `stringstream` to clear its data, you can use its `str()` method instead to assign a blank string.  And you certainly don't need to `swap()`/`clear()` a container variable that will be going out of scope afterwards.

Comment: @RemyLebeau duly noted! I was thinking of using 'std::stod()' before however there were some troubles with it so i decided to whip up a temporary solution using stringstream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input file, as posted, does not have `,` in any of the lines. Hence, use of

```
while (getline(fileopen, line, ',')){
```

does not make sense. Use

```
while (getline(fileopen, line)){
```